# Improve Wine compatibility with legal/valid install of Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, wine

This is a fairly broad question that I am not even sure has an answer.  But, my lack of technical experiences in this field renders me unable to improve upon.

I have a valid install of Windows that I can successfully install on my machine or virtual machine if needed.  Since Wine runs on Windows DLL's, is it possible to *import* such DLL's and default Windows applications into Wine itself?

From what I have heard, Wine itself is different from the true Windows environment, at a kernel level, containing different unintentional bugs resulting in unexpected behavior, which may render this useless.

---

Basically, I ask, can I copy over the `Windows` directory to Wine and anything else I may need to for it to be functional, things such as the *Registry*. How would this be done?

Comment: No. This does not seem to be possible. More technically oriented people may give a more detailed answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a valid install of Windows that I can successfully install on my machine or virtual machine if needed. Since Wine runs on Windows DLL's, is it possible to import such DLL's and default Windows applications into Wine itself?

Wine is not an emulator, the name Wine, literally stands for **Wine Is Not an Emulator**.  Wine does not import Windows DLLs it only translates Windows API calls into POSIX calls.    **This is the reason some applications are supported and some applications are not supported**

> Wine translates Windows API calls into POSIX calls on-the-fly,
> eliminating the performance and memory penalties of other methods and
> allowing you to cleanly integrate Windows applications into your desktop
>
> From what I have heard, Wine itself is different from the true Windows environment, at a kernel level, containing different unintentional bugs resulting in unexpected behavior, which may render this useless.

Wine is not actually a kernel.

> can I copy over the Windows directory to Wine and anything else I may need to for it to be functional, things such as the Registry. How would this be done?

This would not acomplish anything.

Comment: Poster: See [DLL Overrides](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User's_Guide#DLL_Overrides).